# How to run shrinkpdf.sh in Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, shell, software-installation

I am trying to reduce my Rplots' sizes so I am trying the sh script. 
Settings

```
# http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/
masi@masi:~/Documents$ ls -la shrinkpdf.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 masi masi 3107 Nov 15 23:12 shrinkpdf.sh
```

I run it

```
masi@masi:~/Documents$ ./shrinkpdf.sh Rplots.bland.altman.3.pdf > out.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Ghostscript: 9.06
Test file: basic outputs of R

Comment: Broken pdf file?

Comment: Yes, i've tried on some pdfs myself (jessie & stretch). No error, smaller pdf output. (with a very-very low quality)

Comment: i'm afraid of the quality doesn't meet your expectations. https://s11.postimg.org/ub1u4ewhv/gkrell_Shoot_2016_11_16_030827.png <-- 1st one is the shrinked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IporSircer's answer in comments. 
The quality decreases significantly, more than expected, in Fig. 1. 
So reject the method.

[image]